# Unable to create CDK script for Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream

Tags: python, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have to create a CDK script for the deployment of the data pipeline. I already created the lambda function, SNS topic, S3 bucket (very easily), but I struggle while creating the Kinesis Firehose delivery stream for putting files into the S3 bucket.

My stack.py code for Kinesis Firehose delivery stream so far but it is not working:

```
      delivery_stream = firehose.CfnDeliveryStream(
            self, "CdkworkshopFirehose",
            s3_destination_configuration=firehose.CfnDeliveryStream.S3DestinationConfigurationProperty(
                bucket_arn=destination_bucket.bucket_arn,
                buffering_hints=firehose.CfnDeliveryStream.BufferingHintsProperty(
                    interval_in_seconds=60
                ),
                compression_format="UNCOMPRESSED",
                role_arn=" "
            )
        )
```

Does anyone know where is the problem and why? Because this code returns an error:

```
CdkworkshopFirehose Model validation failed (#/S3DestinationConfiguration/RoleARN: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role ARN is mandatory and if you take a look at the error message it tells you where the problem is (I have highlighted it):

> CdkworkshopFirehose Model validation failed (#**/S3DestinationConfiguration/RoleARN**: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern])

The problem is part of the `S3DestinationConfiguration`, which means your `firehose.CfnDeliveryStream.S3DestinationConfigurationProperty` and in there the `RoleARN` doesn't match the pattern that defines a valid role ARN.

**Solution**: create a role and reference it's ARN or input the ARN of an existing role.

Comment: I figured it out, but I couldn't find any example of creating a role in CDK

Comment: And I've tried to input the ARN of existing role from console, but it didn't work also.

Comment: Ok, can you maybe add a separate answer so future readers can benefit from it?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
firehose_role = iam.Role(self, "firehose-role", assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("firehose.amazonaws.com"))
firehose_role_arn = firehose_role.role_arn


        delivery_stream = firehose.CfnDeliveryStream(
            self, "CdkworkshopFirehose",
            s3_destination_configuration=firehose.CfnDeliveryStream.S3DestinationConfigurationProperty(
                bucket_arn=destination_bucket.bucket_arn,
                buffering_hints=firehose.CfnDeliveryStream.BufferingHintsProperty(
                    interval_in_seconds=60
                ),
                compression_format="UNCOMPRESSED",
                role_arn=firehose_role_arn
            )
        )
```